# Change entry on MySQL through CentOS command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line, mariadb, centos7

For a class assignment I had to create a database and put 3 entries in. There were 8 fields to have information input, so to save time and not retype everything, I just hit the up arrow to modify the input, but I forgot to change the ID, so all 3 entries have the ID of 1. 
 
My original code to for input into my table was.

```
Insert into People (id, FirstName, LastName, StreetAddr, City, State, Zip, Phone)
Values (1, "My firstname", "My lastname", "123 Main Street", "my City", "My State", "my Zip", "My phone number");
```

So, in my attempt to save time I messed up and put 1 as all 3 ID numbers, and now I don't know the correct way to edit a single part of an entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pop quiz that might get you to the point of fixing your problem for yourself...

- What does your `CREATE TABLE` say?
- Did the teacher talk about `PRIMARY KEY`?
- Shouldn't `id` by `AUTO_INCREMENT`?
- What value do you feed to `id` to get it to increment automatically?
- What happens if you leave `id` and `1` out of the `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by updating the values.

```
UPDATE People SET id = <put new id here> WHERE FirstName = '<FirstName goes here>' AND LastName = '<LastName goes here>';
```

This assumes that the `FirstName` and `LastName` values are unique enough to find only a single row. Replace the `WHERE` condition values to match the correct ones and choose a new value for the `id`.

Read the [`UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/update/) documentation for more information about the syntax.